# how i can to realize inheritance chain?

Tags: javascript, oop

Have some problem with inheritance. How to implement type inheritance from Some Pencil to Another Pencil? Need: pen3.type // common

```
  class Pencil {
     constructor(color) {
      this.color = color;
    }
    intro() {
      console.log(`this is ${this.color} pencil`);
     }
    };

    class SomePencil extends Pencil {
     constructor(color, type) {
      super(color);
       this.type = type;
     }
    };
    class AnotherPencil extends SomePencil {
      constructor(color,type) {
       super(color, type);
     }
    };

    let pen1 = new Pencil();
    let pen2 = new SomePencil("red", "common");
    let pen3 = new AnotherPencil("green");

    console.log("type" in pen3); // true
```

Comment: I'm not clear what you need. Do you want all instances of AnotherPencil to have type="common"?

Comment: `pen3.type !== undefined`

Comment: `pen3` has a property `type` because `SomePencil` has a `type` but that type is undefined because it hasn't been set with a value when the constructor is called. This is the way it's supposed to work. What do you want the result to be?

Comment: Remember to always [favor Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Comment: Fix it by calling `const pen3 = new AnotherPencil("green", "common");`

Comment: @MarkMeyer i understand now, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inheritance will only inherit properties and not values unless they are set in the class definition itself. For example

```
class SomePencil extends Pencil {
 constructor(color, type) {
  super(color);
   this.type = type || 'common'; // Setting a default value if type is not passed
 }
};
```

new way to set defaults

```
class SomePencil extends Pencil {
 constructor(color, type = 'common') {
  super(color);
   this.type = type;
 }
};
```

Refer [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2a6eburt/)